# how to get ID from file

Tags: c#, split

how to get 3 from `3.hpdf`

if it is a big int then how can i get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function for that:

```
  string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
  int id = int.Parse(name);
```

That only works if your filenames look like 12345.hpdf

Comment: Filenames are strings too. And the `int id = ...` part is optional. Note that you will get better answers if you put a little more effort (and information) in your questions. I'm still not certain what you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful.

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
```